# Pandas, adding multiple columns of list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this one

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g','g']], 'B' : [['1', '4', 'a'], ['5', 'a']]})
```

I would like to create another column C that will be a column of list like the others but this one will be the "union" of the others
Something like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'g']], 'B' : [['1', '4', 'a'], ['5', 'a']], 'C' : [['a', 'b', 'c', '1', '4', 'a'], ['e', 'f', 'g', 'g', '5', 'a']]})
```

But i have like hundreds of columns and C will be the "union" of these hundreds of columns i dont want to index on it like this :

```
df['C'] = df['A'] + df['B]
```

And i dont want to make a for loop because the dataframe i am manipulating are too big and i want something fast

Thank you for helping

Comment: `df["C"] = df[hundreds_of_columns].sum(axis=1)`

Comment: i) summing lists is an anti-pattern to merge them ii) having lists in cells of dataframe is unpreferable

Answer (score 1):

As you have lists, you cannot vectorize the operation.

A list comprehension might be the fastest:

```
from itertools import chain
df['out'] = [list(chain.from_iterable(x[1:])) for x in df.itertuples()]
```

Example:

```
              A          B       C                       out
0     [a, b, c]  [1, 4, a]  [x, y]  [a, b, c, 1, 4, a, x, y]
1  [e, f, g, g]     [5, a]     [z]     [e, f, g, g, 5, a, z]
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @mozway 's answer, you could try something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'f', 'g','g']], 'B' : [['1', '4', 'a'], ['5', 'a']]})
df['C'] = df.sum(axis=1).astype(str)
```

use 'astype' as required for list contents

Comment: this is a very bad idea. Using `sum(axis=1)` is quadratic on lists/strings, performance will be terrible for many columns

Comment: I didn't realise, i may have to change some of my own code!

Comment: If you want to test: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(1000,1000))).astype(str)`, then compare `df.sum(axis=1)` and `df.apply(''.join, axis=1)` (1s vs 100ms)

Comment: Not sure I've done the best method to validate this as it seems to say its only twice as long to use my method. Still significantly worse though! Thank you for teaching me a faster method :)

Answer (score -1):

you can use the  apply method

```
df['C']=df.apply(lambda x: [' '.join(i) for i in list(x[df.columns.to_list()])], axis=1)
```